# GitHub reademe Error: Please add an env variable called PAT_1 with your github token in vercel

Tags: github, readme

I used this in my GitHub readme.

```
<img align="center" height="170" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=[GitHub UserName]&layout=compact&langs_count=16&theme=dracula"/>
```

But it says now, "Something went wrong! file an issue at https://tiny.one/readme-stats Maximum retries exceeded Please add an env variable called PAT_1 with your github token in vercel"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used this and it resolved the problem.

```
<img align="center" height="170" src="https://github-readme-stats-sigma-five.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=lucky-bruce&layout=compact&langs_count=16&theme=dracula"/>
```

Comment: It seems like working with this.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are facing the same issue you should only add a variable increasing the token's

This is what I had with the error:

```
<a href=""><img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=YulietM&theme=react&line_height=40&hide=css"/> </a>
```

and adding (***sigma-five***) to src url solved the issue ->

```
<a href=""><img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats-sigma-five.vercel.app/api/top-langs/?username=YulietM&theme=react&line_height=40&hide=css"/> </a>
```

[check here for original answer](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats/issues/2149#issuecomment-1373812812)

Answer (score 0):

I added (sigma-five) and it worked too

```
<img align="center" src="https://github-readme-stats-sigma-five.vercel.app/api/top-langs?username=muhd-dev&langs_count=10&show_icons=true&locale=en&layout=compact&theme=dark" alt="Top Languages" height="192px" width="500px" />
```